# Issue with Query using Aurora-MySQL works with MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We have a simple query that checks if a record exists in one table that has the id of another. If so it returns the id. This works for small data sets such as the working example below in Aurora.

However, if we have a lot of ids (like 1000) the first query returns 0 rows and the second succeeds in Aurora but works on MySQL.

We have been unable to see any optimizations or other gaps in Aurora MySQL that would explain this behavior. Any advice or guidance is appreciated.

Working example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table_1` (
  `id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `test_table_2` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_table_1_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `another_id` char(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_table_1_id_foreign` (`test_table_1_id`),
  KEY `another_id_index` (`another_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_table_1_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`test_table_1_id`) REFERENCES `test_table_1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test_table_1` (`id`)
VALUES
('e54b3097-21ff-4d7d-8bee-5aa62e66d9b6'),
('4fada427-ef5a-455d-ad55-831de6192dc1');

INSERT INTO `test_table_2` (`test_table_1_id`, `another_id`)
VALUES
('e54b3097-21ff-4d7d-8bee-5aa62e66d9b6', 'aeef668e-1365-41e8-a4a7-026d9a021935'),
('4fada427-ef5a-455d-ad55-831de6192dc1', '61e7b307-e356-4537-bcc5-927c3c217992');


SELECT * FROM `test_table_1`
WHERE `id` = 'e54b3097-21ff-4d7d-8bee-5aa62e66d9b6' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test_table_2`
    WHERE `test_table_2`.`another_id` = 'aeef668e-1365-41e8-a4a7-026d9a021935'
    AND `test_table_2`.`test_table_1_id` = `test_table_1`.`id`);

SELECT * FROM `test_table_1`
WHERE `id` = '4fada427-ef5a-455d-ad55-831de6192dc1' 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test_table_2`
    WHERE `test_table_2`.`another_id` = '61e7b307-e356-4537-bcc5-927c3c217992'
    AND `test_table_2`.`test_table_1_id` = `test_table_1`.`id`);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're happy to have you here. Can I ask when you say it isn't working, can you elaborate? Does it return an error? If so, what is the exact error message? Does it return no error, but a result you don't expect? If so, what did you expect, and what does it return instead?

Comment: "Fails" -- meaning that it returns zero rows instead of one row?  With the values given?  Or with different UUIDs?

Comment: @RickJames exactly, it returns zero rows instead of any rows.  Explain shows no difference between how it is running in Aurora vs MySQL

Comment: @BrentBartlett - But are the UUIDs the same?

Comment: @RickJames the UUIDs are identical between both yes, when only two records are shown like the small sample it works fine however if a large amount are shown it does not work.  I'll see if I can generate a sample set to show it.  This happens with about 1000 records.

Comment: @BrentBartlett - What you have described is strange.  I will eagerly experiment with a failing test case.